# What does "兄者など" mean?

Tags: particle-など

I read a doujinshi about an older brother who was teased by his younger brother, and the younger brother said "兄者など". I don't really get what it means. Someone please help me ;__;

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It means "such a brother", or "like this type of brother(if that's what the context meant).
It seems to like :" such a (bad/good/handsome etc.) brother"
兄-elder brother
者-nature/type
など-alike

Answer (score 12):

The など is used as a belittling / derogatory suffix. (≂なんか) e.g:

> - 「お[兄]{にい}ちゃんなんか！」 (≂ 「[兄者]{あにじゃ}など！」← sounds literary/archaic)
> - 「お前なんか！」"The heck with you!"

It's definition #2 in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/164368/meaning/m0u/):

> ある事物を例示し、特にそれを**軽んじて扱う**意を表す。 **否定的**な表現の中で多く使われる。… **なんか** 。…なんて。「わたしのことなどお忘れでしょう」「金などいるものか」

Answer (score 1):

[兄者]{あにじゃ} was the term of calling one's older brother before the early modern period in Japan.
That use only in a television drama.

A meaning of など depends on the context.
I think that has meanings like 'and so on' and 'such'.

I guess that younger brother imitates TV on purpose.